# How to fix "Consider defining a bean of type 'org.jooq.DSLContext' in your configuration." after update to jOOQ 3.15.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, jooq, r2dbc

In my Vaadin and Spring Boot application, I have updated from jOOQ 3.14.12 to 3.15.0. After this update my application is not starting up again. This is the error I get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.komunumo.data.service.MemberService required a bean of type 'org.jooq.DSLContext' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.jooq.DSLContext' in your configuration.
```

I don't understand why I have to define this bean, because with jOOQ 3.14.12 I did not have to. As far as I know, this is done by `JooqAutoConfiguration` automatically.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Spring Boot 2.6 answer

With Spring Boot 2.6, this issue no longer reproduces, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26439

#### Spring Boot 2.5 answer

Starting from jOOQ 3.15.0, jOOQ ships with a built-in [R2DBC](https://r2dbc.io/) dependency. Spring Boot 2.5 is not yet aware of this, and as such, you'll have to explicitly exclude `R2dbcAutoConfiguration` (*not* `R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration`!) from your spring boot application (unless you're using R2DBC with jOOQ, of course):

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Note, you may see the following error message:

> No qualifying bean of type 'org.jooq.DSLContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Which I'm adding here, because otherwise, people might not find this answer from Google.